# Case and Sum of Multiple columns

Tags: sql

In my database I have several thousand customers, with certain criteria happening at different intervals. There are columns for each day of the week (M,Tu,W,Th,F,Sa,Su). I need to see how many days a week that a task will be triggered. I have the query below but it of course also returns the specific day of the week along with the TotalDays per week. However, I need to see just the TotalDays and not additional display each individual day. How can I accomplish this?

```
SELECT X.*,M+Tu+W+Th+F+Sa+Su AS TotalDays
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "M",
        CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Tu",
        CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "W",
        CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Th",
        CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "F",
        CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Sa",
        CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "Su"
    FROM
        Customers
    ) X
```

I should say that the data type here is bit so I can't just do a Sum of days such as the following as this returns an error that the data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

```
SELECT 
 (SUM(M) + SUM(Tu) + SUM(W) + SUM(Th) + SUM(F) + SUM(Sa) + SUM(Su)) as TotalDays
FROM Customers
```

Comment: What if you use COUNT instead of SUM?

Comment: COUNT does not work as it returns 7 for every customer, so it counts both the 0 and 1 values. As mentioned, SUM does not work I get the returned error that the data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          )
FROM Customers;
```